# How can the Vss or Vdd pins of a MCU handle sink or source current?

Tags: microcontroller, current, avr, stm32

Today I was seeing the datasheet of [STM32F103](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00191185.pdf) MCUs and I came across with an interesting thing. assume I have an STM32F103RET6. it's a 64pin MCU of STM32 series. the pinout is this:

[image: figure1]

It has 4 `Vss` and or `Vdd` and 51 `GPIO` pins (the rest of pins are ain't important for my question). look at `Absolute maximum ratings`

[image: figure2]

The total current that all `Vss` or `Vdd` can source or sink is 4*150=600mA. as I said we have 51 GPIO pins. if we would use them as source or sink for current then they would draw 51*(+-25)= (+-1275). the point is that the total current that all `Vss` or `Vdd` can handle is less than 600mA while the total current for GPIOs is 1275mA. **Why?**

also that's not only belong to STM32 family. I have checked out AVR family. for example [ATmega8a](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8159-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8A_datasheet.pdf). DIP package:

[image: figure3]

It has one `Vcc` and one `GND` while there are 22 `GPIO`s. each `Vcc` or `GND` (ATmega8a for DIP package just has one `Vcc` and `GND`) just can handle 300mA while there are 22 `GPIO` and the total current is 22*40=880mA. also for `MLF` or `TQFP` packages, it's better than `DIP` because they have a couple `GND` and `Vcc`.

Comment: Because you're not supposed to try to blow the ass out of your MCU.

Comment: Sinking outputs do not sink their currents from the MCU's VCC but from the external loads (that should contain their own power supplies). About the sourcing outputs - maybe, their total sum of currents should not exceed the VCC's maximum.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams LoL!

Comment: @Circuitfantasist: No, the MCU, like all CMOS chips, sources from Vcc/Vdd and sinks to GND/Vss. There's no other way to complete the circuit.

Comment: OK, I see... my remark was irrelevant here... It concerns more the loading of the power sources...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All this is saying it that the maximum current, either sinking or sourcing, is 150 mA for the entire chip..  This is probably dictated by heat considerations.

If you had all 51 GPIO pins drawing current, the average would have to be just under 3 mA (150/51) to avoid going over the 150 mA limit.  (Actually you could nearly 6 mA per pin, if half were sourcing current and the other half were sinking.  But that would be pretty unusual.)

But rather than limit each pin to 3 mA (or 6mA), the spec allows each pin to draw up to 25 mA.  But if you have six pins sinking 25 mA each, then you have used up your total of 150 mA and all other pins must not be sinking any current (although they could be sourcing some).